# ¿Como dividir un dataframe en bloques?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Mi dataframe de forma simplificada es algo así:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | casa |
| B | carro |
| C | perro |
| A | finca |
| B | moto |
| C | gato |
| D | invierno |
| A | casa |
| B | moto |
| C | ave |

y quisiera dividirlo para que quede en diferentes dataframes de la siguiente forma:

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | casa |
| B | carro |
| C | perro |

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | finca |
| B | moto |
| C | gato |
| D | invierno |

| col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- |
| A | casa |
| B | moto |
| C | ave |

Es decir que cada vez que aparezca A, cambie de dataframe indiferentemente del tamaño, pero no he encontrado como hacerlo. Agradezco si me pueden ayudar con esto.

Comment: ¿No has encontrado o no has buscado? `iloc` es tu amigo.

Comment: He probado con iloc y me funiona cuando los bloques son de tamaños iguales, pero como los bloques son de tamaños diferentes no se como hacer para dividir el dataframe siempre que la columna sea igual a A. Y quisiera hacerlo de forma automática, no contando el tamaño de cada bloque, ya que las columnas son un ejemplo simplificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) nos permite generar un dataframe a partir de los índices inicial y final que lo compongan.

Por lo tanto sólo necesitamos saber dónde están las filas que serán el inicio y final de nuestros nuevos dataframes.

Necesitamos una lista de filas cuya columna `col_1` valga `'A'`.
Esto es fácil de hacer:

```
indices_a = df.index[df['col_1'] == 'A'].tolist()
```

Asumo que la primera fila de la columna `col_1` siempre valdrá `A`.
De no ser así habría que añadir al principio de `indices_a` un índice 0.
Independientemente de cuál sea el último valor de la columna `col_1` necesitamos completar esta lista con el último índice.

```py
indices_a.append(len(df.index))
```

Para iterar esta lista usaremos [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise).
Creamos la nueva lista de dataframes así:

```py
dataframes = [df.iloc[inicio:fin]
              for inicio, fin in pairwise(indices_a)]
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. Aunque la respuesta pueda solucionar el problema, la pregunta no cumple con los requisitos mínimos de la comunidad. Responder a preguntas que no muestran un intento por parte del autor incentivan la holgazanería.